# Use textbox in monaco editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, monaco-editor

I am new to monaco editor and its' really good.  I just noticed that it doesn't work on text box control.

it's working on div

```
<div id="ComponentTemplateHTML" style="width:1000px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>
```

but in text box or text area it's not working

```
 <textarea asp-for="ComponentTemplateHTML" style="width:1000px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></textarea>



require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../../lib/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
        require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {


monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("ComponentTemplateHTML"), {
            language: "css",
            scrollbar: {
                vertical: 'auto',
                horizontal: 'auto'
            }
        });
```

Comment: By default `monaco editor` creates text area, but it requires a div element for wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy contents from `div` to `textarea` when form is submitted so it will be send out with form as an input. Remember to make that `textarea` hidden or make that `textarea` dynamically.

***jQuery Example***

```
$( "#your-form-id" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $ ('#your-textarea-id').val( $('#your-monaco-div-id') );
});
```